# AngularJS, $http and interceptor - every request received twice in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to use AngularJS' $http interceptor for adding a token on every API call.

This is my code (http://pastebin.com/x1EMGcVE):

```
.factory('authInterceptor', function(authorization, API) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            var token = authorization.getToken();
            if (config.url.indexOf(API) === 0 && token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = token;
            }
            return config;
        }
    }
})
```

On my nodes backend I'm receiving the call with express:

```
app.route('/API-CALL')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        ...
```

My problem is that every API request is received twice in nodejs, one request without the token added in Authorization and one with the token added.

Is this an issue with the interceptor? Outputting the config from the interceptor seems to show no issues and only the correct number of requests with the token added.

If I remove the:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

calls are only made once, but of course without the token added.

Comment: nothing strange in your code, problem can be in part that call $http

Comment: One example on call that gets requested twice: $http.get(API + '/cars').then(function(res) { $scope.cars = res.data.cars; });

Comment: If I out comment the interceptor calls are not made twice. Also, some times on refresh the browser calls are only made once. But usually twice.

Comment: Could be something to due with CORS? As in Safari every request is made twice, in Chrome everything fails with "preflight".

Comment: if you made cross domain requests every request consist of two requests: 1) HEAD for CORS headers 2) your main request

Comment: @AlexeyB. but why once commented out it sends only one request?